# How can I improve this Keras model that predicts whether a given number is odd or even

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a tensorflow keras deep learning model to predict whether a number is odd vs even. However, I cannot figure out how to actually make it work. It's current accuracy ranges between 40-60%, making me assume its just guessing. How can I improve this model? I also have no idea what loss function to use. This is my first model so I am very much a noob. I have also tried changing the layer sizes and that doesn't seem to yield much either. I have also tried varying the size of my sample data (random numbers with a label list of whether they are odd or even). I used as little as 50 to as high as the full 10000. Any help is much appreciated!

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#The next few lines just import and preprocess the data

dataFile = open('oddEvenData.txt','r')
dataLabels = open('oddEvenLabels.txt','r')

data = dataFile.read()
labels = dataLabels.read()

train_data = data.split(',')
train_labels = labels.split(',')

train_data.remove('')
train_labels.remove('')

train_data = [int(x) for x in train_data]
train_labels = [int(x) for x in train_labels]

dataFile.close()
dataLabels.close()

#Creates and pre process's test data set

test_data = [[123],[56],[273],[834],[778]]
test_labels = [[0],[1],[0],[1],[1]]

test_data = np.array(test_data)
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

test_data = test_data/10000

#Builds framework

model = keras.Sequential([
                          keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu',input_shape = (1,)),
                          keras.layers.Dense(128,activation = 'relu'),
                          keras.layers.Dense(64,activation = 'relu'),
                          keras.layers.Dense(2,activation = 'softmax')
])


model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_data,train_labels,epochs = 10)

test_loss,test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data,test_labels)

print('Tested Acc:'+str(test_acc))

testNum = [int(input('Input test num: '))]

prediction = model.predict(np.array(testNum))
print(prediction)
```

Comment: There is a difference in your question title and description. Are you trying to predict odd vs even or positive vs negative ?

Comment: Odd vs even. That's my bad.

Comment: "How can I improve this model?" Well, you could model the numbers as a binary flag depending on whether they're odd or even making your model redundant. I know this is not the answer you're looking for but it might be the reason you're not getting helpful answers. Asking questions how you can apply machine learning to problems where you shouldn't use machine learning in the first place are a little strange to me.